# Did Russian pluralization break in Xcode 14 for bvOS?

Tags: swift, xcode, unit-testing, tvos, xcode14

I using https://unicode-org.github.io/cldr-staging/charts/37/supplemental/language_plural_rules.html for making .stringsdict file.

It looks like: [image: pluralization of week]

So I met the bug, that in Xcode 14 in Test target the pluralization not working as expected. It return `XCTAssertEqual failed: ("199 ₽ за 30 недели") is not equal to ("199 ₽ за 30 недель")` Should be `недель` instead of `недели`.

But previously everything work well. And no code did change. Maybe someone met same problem? Maybe something changed in new Xcode in Test only for pluralization? Any information appreciated!

Important that the same test in iOS works well. For tvOS it fail.

Comment: Post relevant code in your question so people can try to replicate the issue.

Comment: File a bug with Apple, please.

Comment: Created. `FB11812422 (Pluralization for tvOS in Test works wrong.)`